# Using xml_grep to extract certain fields in an xml file and saving into a tsv file

Tags: xml

I need to extract a defined list of fields in XML files then save them into a tsv file, with the extracted fields separated by tab. For example, in this xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PC-AssayDescription
    xmlns="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/specifications/pubchem.xsd"
>
  <PC-AssayDescription_aid>
    <PC-ID>
      <PC-ID_id>720001</PC-ID_id>
      <PC-ID_version>1</PC-ID_version>
    </PC-ID>
  </PC-AssayDescription_aid>
  <PC-AssayDescription_aid-source>
    <PC-Source>
      <PC-Source_db>
        <PC-DBTracking>
          <PC-DBTracking_name>ChEMBL</PC-DBTracking_name>
          <PC-DBTracking_source-id>
            <Object-id>
              <Object-id_str>887744</Object-id_str>
            </Object-id>
          </PC-DBTracking_source-id>
        </PC-DBTracking>
      </PC-Source_db>
    </PC-Source>
  </PC-AssayDescription_aid-source>
  <PC-AssayDescription_name>Inhibition of rabbit ERG channel assessed as decrease in monophasic action potential duration</PC-AssayDescription_name>
```

I need to extract text between these two tags:

```html
<PC-ID_id>720001</PC-ID_id>
<PC-AssayDescription_name>Inhibition of rabbit ERG channel assessed as decrease in monophasic action potential duration</PC-AssayDescription_name>
```

And I used this batch script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.xml
do
((xml_grep 'PC-ID_id' $f --text_only; xml_grep 'PC-AssayDescription_name' $f --text_only;) | tr '\n' '     '; echo) >> result.tsv
done
```

If I run the script, it will generate a tsv file like this:

720001 (tab) Inhibition of rabbit ERG channel assessed as decrease in monophasic action potential duration

Results from multiple XML files will be put into different rows. If all the XML files have non-blank text between these two tags, each row of the result.tsv file will be the same format (two non-blank columns).

However, if any of the two tags have blank content in an XML file, it will be missing in the corresponding row of the tsv file and change the column format of that row. What I need is if a tag has blank content in an XML file, the script returns a "N/A", which will keep the structure of each row of the result.tsv consistent.